# service is not working in a simple controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have this js code

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.service('testService', function(){
  this.sayHello= function(text){
    return "Service says \"Hello " + text + "\"";
  };
  this.sayGoodbye = function(text){
    return "Service says \"Goodbye " + text + "\"";
  };
});


app.controller('AboutCtrl', ['testService', function ($scope, $location, $http) {


  $scope.fromService = testService.sayHello("World");
  $scope.toService = testService.sayGoodbye("World");
}]);
```

and in my html I have this

....
...
    
      hi {{fromService}}
    
....
...

There are no errors in console and the page is just blank.

Comment: Did you place an `ng-app` declaration anywhere in your HTML?

Comment: add `testService ` as dependency in `app.controller('AboutCtrl', ['testService', function ($scope, $location, $http) {` line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please take a look at AngularJs Docs "Using Dependency Injection".

The correct way:

```
app.controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 
'testService', function ($scope, $location, $http, testService) {
        $scope.fromService = testService.sayHello("World");
        $scope.toService = testService.sayGoodbye("World");
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can inject your service to controller by these ways.

**Inline Array Annotation**

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'testService', function($scope, testService) {
  // ...Code here
}]);
```

**$inject Property Annotation**

```
var MyController = function($scope, testService) {
  // ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'testService'];
app.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

**Implicit Annotation**

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, testService) {
  // ...
});
```

if you want to know which one is preferred  then read this [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Answer (score 1):

You're not injecting your service properly.

```
app.controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 
'testService', function ($scope, $location, $http, testService) {

        $scope.fromService = testService.sayHello("World");

        $scope.toService = testService.sayGoodbye("World");

}]);
```

Also in your `HTML` you should add `ng-app="app"` and `ng-controller` to especify your controller.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head></head>
    <body ng-controller="AboutCtrl">
        <p>Hi {{fromService}}</p>

     <!-- Also place here your JS files.-->>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Supper easy, Actually you are injecting service wrong place check this:

```
app.controller('aboutCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $http, testService) {
$scope.fromService = testService.sayHello("World");
$scope.toService = testService.sayGoodbye("World");
});
```